# How to auto-fill this password, web form popup?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, greasemonkey, basic-authentication

I'm trying to auto fill a popup / alert web form:
[image: Popup form]

So far it seems that Greasemonkey may be able to solve this problem for me but my javascript is nearly nonexistent.

I've come across [Xavi's autofill Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/39313). While it seems to work great when a form is embedded in the page I'm not sure if it's capable of popup / alert windows (dialogs).

I've also come across [curl's formfind.pl](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/perl/contrib/formfind) but it produces errors half the time and then there is the question of the pop up / alert window.

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That popup dialog is for ["Basic authentication"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), and it occurs at a low-level between the browser and the web-server.  It happens before the webpage loads and **before Greasemonkey has any possibility to see it.**

A Firefox add-on could manipulate this form, but those are much more involved to write.  Anyway, there are several add-ons out there, already, to help with this.  I use [***Secure Login***](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/secure-login/), which plugs some holes in Firefox's password management, simplifies logins, and can even make bookmarks to the logged-in state of some websites.

For other possibilities see, the answers to ["How to automate basic authentication password confirm dialog"](https://superuser.com/q/46191/41023), and similar questions.

Comment: Definitely the most detailed answer here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication popup type is on top of all elements from any browser. You cannot do any action after the popup appears except Ok & Cancel.

Answer (score -1):

This prompt will pop-up before any line of source code from your Page will be executed so i don't see any way how you could pre fill it.